# RIAK: How to search for records in JSON?

Tags: php, json, mapreduce, riak, riak-search

How to search for records in JSON?

For example:

> http://server.cc/riak/Scores/user12
>
> { v: "{"score":0,"tab":14,"gold":255}" }

How do I get all the records where the "gold" is more than 150 or equal 255?

I'm installed the Riak Search hook on bucket.
I have used example from riak php lib.

```
 $client = new Riak(self::HOST, self::PORT);
 $bucket = $client->bucket("Scores");
 $results = $client->search("Scores", "gold:255")->run();
```

doesn't have results.

Can this be done through mapreduce?

Answer (score 1):

Just saw this pass by on the Riak Users mailing list:

http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2013-June/012286.html

> "gold" is nested so I believe the search term would be :
>
> v_gold:255
>
> An underscore is used as the delimiter between nested keys.
>
> -Alexander Sicular

Answer (score 0):

let, you have a json object like this:

```
var goldJson=
    [
        {"score": ,   "tab": , "gold": 255},
        {"score": ,   "tab": , "gold": 256},
        {"score": , "tab": , "gold": 257}
    ]
```

now you can get the gold more than 150 or equal to 255 by using the following codes:

```
for(var i = 0; i < goldJson.length; i++)
{
  if(goldJson[i].gold >150 || goldJson[i].gold == 255)
  {
    //get gold More than 150 or equal to 255
  }
}
```

Comment: Rayhan, thanks.
But, how do I get a list from the riak-server?

Comment: you can see the following example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875126/php-riak-list-buckets